# Create a new column multiplying a column and an array with unequal lengths

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, loops, python-3.7

I have the following columns:

```
Date                    
2010-01-04  NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2010-01-05  0.012724    0.015659    0.000266    0.003344    0.022251
2010-01-06  0.004910    -0.020427   -0.022870   -0.014700   -0.030640
2010-01-07  -0.022239   -0.017900   -0.028223   -0.022729   -0.021563
2010-01-08  0.025978    -0.015153   -0.020648   -0.024394   -0.023600
... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-08-25  -0.000171   -0.003003   0.012596    0.008506    0.001257
2021-08-26  -0.009339   -0.004284   0.003506    -0.004533   0.011284
2021-08-27  -0.002833   0.009494    0.013068    -0.011000   -0.003862
2021-08-30  -0.018293   -0.003945   -0.005080   -0.006311   0.000387
2021-08-31  0.019848    0.013350    0.022745    0.004935    0.016115
2875 rows × 5 columns
```

I am trying to create a new column that will be the sum of multiplication of each row of the columns with respective weights as an output.

Weights are as follows:

```
array([0.12123039, 0.31162947, 0.27817099, 0.10452567, 0.18444348])
```

For eg.

On 2010-01-05:

New column value = (0.012724 * 0.12123039 + 0.015659 * 0.31162947 + 0.000266 * 0.27817099 + 0.003344 * 0.10452567 + 0.022251 * 0.18444348)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['new_column'] = df.mul(weights).sum(axis=1)
```